# Is this a proper way to present Back and Next buttons in Android app?

Tags: android

As part of a Quiz app, in which users have to go through a set of questions, I need to provide the ability to:

1. Quit the quiz
2. Go to next question
3. Go (back) to the previous question

I am trying to implement some Material Design principles into my design. Is this a legit way of doing this - having the back and next buttons in the bottom bar? Please advise.

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: I cat see the screenshot. Please upload to http://imgur.com

Comment: How about a message "swipe to continue"? You'd show this only on the first question. Users would then intuitively swipe in the opposite direction if they wished to go back.

Answer (score 1):

Having the back and next at the bottom interferes with the number/alphanumeric keyboard and material sheets that slides up from the bottom.

- Use the native android action bar to display consistent navigation
  and view switches within the app.
- Use the native "Input Controls" for your "next button" following
  Googles design standards.

Visit google.com/design
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html

And for native controls visit the Android developers site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How about Back and Close/Quit in the action bar, and a contextual Swipe to Continue call for action at the bottom bar, which will appear only after user has made a selection / answered the quiz question?

Comment: While I may be late, I'd like to say that all google login activities use bottom navigation, and back/signout buttons up there look very iphone-ish to me

Comment: See this https://material.google.com/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steps

Answer (score 0):

Buttons at the bottom of the screen are in fact recommended by the Material Design guidelines for navigation purposes like yours.

*From [Understanding navigation: Forward navigation][https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#forward-navigation]:*

> Buttons can provide a clear affordance to advance in a flow through their label, placement, and visual emphasis.

[image]

Therefore, I cannot see anything wrong in your interface design. You might want to add horizontal swiping as well, but other than that, your design looks very well thought-out and intuitive to me.